# How equals method behaves when overloaded?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

So I have below Test code Implementation

```
class Employee{
     String name;
     int age;

    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) return false;

public boolean equals(Employee obj) return true;     
}
```

And in the main method, I have below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Object E1 = new Employee();
    Employee E2 = new Employee();

    System.out.println(E1.equals(E2));

}
```

So as per my understanding, polymorphism should bind E1 with method `equals(Employee obj)` as I am passing the object of type  Employee and E1 instance is also of type Employee (though reference to Object underlying instance is of type Employee).
However, I see that it prints false, which means `equals(Object obj)` has been invoked(Same has been verified using Sysout statement in both equals method).

Comment: Which overloaded method to call is resolved at **compile** time, based on the **declared** type of the arguments and the receiver. Since E1 is of declared type Object, the only possible method to call is equals(Object) (because Object doesn't have any other equals() method). Then polymorhism works at runtime to call the implementation in the Employee class rather than the implementation in the Object class. I'm sure there are dozens of duplicates, which is why I didn't answer.

Comment: How is "behaves" is that it looks like it works until you use it anywhere that actually depends on the contract, then it breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of how binding is done is incorrect.

There are two steps in binding:

1. Decide which overload to call
2. Decide which implementation to call.

The first step is done at compile time and is based on the *compile-time* type of the variable. The second step is done at runtime and is based on the runtime type of the object. The second step is what you refer to as "polymorphism".

During the first step, `E1`'s compile time type is `Object`, so there is only one *overload* of `equals` to choose from - `equals(Object)`. Therefore, that overload is chosen.

During the second step, there are two *implementations* to choose from:

```
// In Employee class:
public boolean equals(Object obj) return false;

// In Object class
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Since `E1`'s *runtime type* is `Employee`, as you have correctly identified, it chooses the implementation in the `Employee` class, which returns false all the time.

Comment: But I am passing Object of type Employee, won't that be considered? Like, In method overriding it's decided on the type of argument

Comment: @sid During the first step, only the compile time type will be considered. The compile time type of `E1` is `Object`, so only methods declared in `Object` will be found. Your `equals(Employee)` method is declared in `Employee`, so it cannot be found. The compiler can't "see" that there is a `equals(Employee)` method, because `E1` is of compile time type `Object`.

Comment: @sid: No, it won't be considered, because that information is not available at compile time.